# Setting up OpenCV in Visual Studio in a global manner

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

I have successfully installed and tested OpenCV in VS 2019 but it only works for a project with a single executable file. Specifically, when I wanted to  run a project with several interdependent files (sub projects) as the following image, I got errors.

[image]

As in the above image, I should run the Demo and other files are dependencies of it.

[image]

What's the way to globally (not locally) integrate OpenCV in VS 2019?

Comment: typically you would add the include directory to each project that needs it. But afaik in VS you can inherit such settings for subprojects, but dont ask me how...

Comment: I think [this page describes how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/vcpp-directories-property-page?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019).